# smtp error: 534 when sending email through gmail in golang app

Tags: email, go, gmail

On my golang app I use [this](https://gist.github.com/jpillora/cb46d183eca0710d909a) snippet to send email from my gmail account:

```
func send(body string) {
    from := "myaccount@gmail.com"
    pass := "mysupersecretpasswd"
    to := "whoever@whatever.com"

    msg := "From: " + from + "\n" +
        "To: " + to + "\n" +
        "Subject: Hello there\n\n" +
        body

    err := smtp.SendMail("smtp.gmail.com:587",
        smtp.PlainAuth("", from, pass, "smtp.gmail.com"),
        from, []string{to}, []byte(msg))

    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("smtp error: %s", err)
        return
    }

    log.Print("sent, visit whatever)
}
```

I get this error instead:

```
smtp error: 534 5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbud
5.7.14 lxVDnr-tXOckmxXi0fxExY5BKDRczBpGvMCpGWGF97jAI5DlM2oeGMDcIkvBhKT9rJAVnH
5.7.14 WP7zxssynLtkzMb35et-wxJF2AfeBhMA81QqMh2F8fkQRdf9GidA3swFnjfsUl0Pw6fiMT
5.7.14 b3zvEJyD6WAKEWcuxEGJIBTaqCtfDjipQ58cFJweUiKg1_4AJp0fGpC9ufnjBGWqWVKeW9
5.7.14 QVbUstROYK0SzjWXTTvsvZhhG3RjM> Please log in via your web browser and
5.7.14 then try again.
5.7.14  Learn more at
5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 61sm6182123wre.44 - gsmtp
```

I have installed postfix on my localhost. I have also allowed less secure apps to access my account. 
I have also tried the same code on my VPS, but it does not send emails either.

So what could be wrong? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've copied your gist, replaced from, to and password and it works flawlessly. The only reason why this code is not working is that you are NOT allowing less secure apps in gmail.

Comment: You are right. Apparently the email not properly set to send from insecure devices. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Google **removed less secure app access** option. Mean, you can not use gmail’s username and password to send emails using code.

Instead you need to **generate a password dedicated to an application**, and use this password instead of your gmail account password within your code, which is more secure :)

Making App Password:

1. Enable 2FA
   https://myaccount.google.com/signinoptions/two-step-verification/enroll-welcome
2. Create an app-specific password
   https://myaccount.google.com/apppasswords

See details and golang examples of how to send an email in [here](https://medium.com/p/e602bc4ac67c)